# XSLT how to output <tr></tr> tags every 3rd iteration

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML and I am trying to group it into 3 `<tag>` into 1 `<tr>` element:

```
<tags>
    <tag>
        <title>Title1</title>
        <img>src1</img>
        <text>text text text</text>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <title>Title2</title>
        <img>src2</img>
        <text>text text text</text>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <title>Title3</title>
        <img>src3</img>
        <text>text text text</text>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <title>Title4</title>
        <img>src4</img>
        <text>text text text</text>
    </tag>
    ...
</tags>
```

I want the following output:

```
<tr>
    <td><h2>Title1</h2> <img src='src1'> <p>text text text</p></td>
    <td><h2>Title2</h2> <img src='src2'> <p>text text text</p></td>
    <td><h2>Title3</h2> <img src='src3'> <p>text text text</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><h2>Title4</h2> <img src='src4'> <p>text text text</p></td>
    ...
</tr>
...
```

I tried doing:

```
<div class='some-class'>
    <table>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 0">
            <tr>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:for-each select="/Tags/Tag" >
            <td>
                <h2><xsl:value-of select="title" /></h2>
                <img src="{src}" />
                <p><xsl:value-of select="text" /></p>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 0">
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the table must be within an existing `<div>` element.

Comment: You should post an example that has at least 4 tags, in order for it to be useful.

Comment: "*And the table must be within an existing <div> element.*" It's not clear what you mean by "existing". I have edited my answer to add a **new** <div> element; if that's not what you mean, edit your question again and add the exact code you expect as the output of the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k What I mean is I already have an xsl:stylesheet with bunch of other stuff. Somewhere in the middle of my page I need to render a table such that it will consist of 3 <tag>'s in each <tr> element. But when I use your code and paste it inside my existing <div> I get this error: " 'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'div' element."

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with code I cannot see. It's true that a template must be a top-level element of the stylesheet.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I can't post all the code in here, because it's humongous :) So is there a way to put your code up top (something like <xsl:template name='bla'>) and then call it where I need it?

Comment: Let's not go in circles. I have already pointed you to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/tags">
    <div class='some-class'>
        <table border="1">
             <xsl:for-each select="tag[position() mod 3 = 1]">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::tag[position() &lt; 3]"/>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
    <td>
        <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </h2>
        <img src="{img}" />
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="text" />
        </p>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's giving me " 'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'div' element." How would I create those templates outside and just apply them in code?

Comment: @N0ir I have posted a **complete** stylesheet that does **NOT** produce this (or any other) error. If you want something else, you need to edit your question and explain what that is. Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve