# Xpath - I need help making a table for an html

Tags: html, xslt, xpath, html-table

I'm trying to make a table with this:

Input:

```
<root>
<vendedor>
     <nombre>nombre1</nombre>
     <descrip>descrip1</descrip>
</vendedor>
 <vendedor>
     <nombre>nombre1</nombre>
     <descrip>descrip2</descrip>
</vendedor>
<vendedor>
     <nombre>nombre1</nombre>
     <descrip>descrip3</descrip>
</vendedor>
....
<vendedor>
     <nombre>nombre2</nombre>
     <descrip>descrip1</descrip>
</vendedor>
<vendedor>
     <nombre>nombre2</nombre>
     <descrip>descrip3</descrip>
</vendedor>
....
</root>
```

xsl:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//vendedor[not(nombre=preceding-sibling::vendedor/nombre)]/nombre">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//vendedor[nombre=current()]/descrip">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What I want is a table like this transforming the xslt into an HTML with tr,td and stuff like this:

```
|_____________nombre____________|
|descrip|descrip|descrip|descrip|
|descrip|descrip|descrip|descrip|
```

I have been trying but I don't get what I want so..., Can someone help me?

Expected output:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>nombre</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
.....
</tr>
....
<tr>
  <th>nombre</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
  <td>descrip</td>
</tr>
.....
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show an example of the input and the expected output (preferably as code, not as a drawing).

Comment: ok, so something like that.

Comment: I still see no input. Anyway, I believe you're find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31706512/3016153

Comment: I was editing the input :p

Answer (score 0):

You can make a table in HTML like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Where `<tr>` stays for rows and `<td>` for columns.

Example from http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

Table for your example would be:

```
  "<table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>nombre</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>"
```

Comment: ok, i will edit, the thing is that i want to transform the xslt into an html and the result a table like this

Comment: Ok, its more or less what i want, but i get more results so, there is a way to do it like more distibuted? i mean, like every 5 td in and tr another tr with 5 td, its possible?